# How to map results of a stored procedure to an existing table in Entity Framework code-first

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

I have an issue while mapping results of a stored procedure (`dbo.sp_Get_User`) to an existing `UserEntity` entity.

I didn't want to user db table column names in my project directly. So I have `UserEntity` as follows:

```
public class UserEntity
{
        public UserEntity()
        {
        }

        public int UserKey { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And my mapper maps all the columns of table to this entity as follows:

```
public class UserEntityMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserEntity>
{
            public UserEntityMapper()
            {
                ToTable("tbl_User");

                HasKey(m => m.UserKey);
                Property(p => p.UserKey).HasColumnName("User_KEY");
                Property(p => p.FirstName).HasColumnName("FIRST_NAME");
                Property(p => p.LastName).HasColumnName("LAST_NAME");
            }
}
```

Now I have a condition where I need to use a stored procedure to get the user data (based on some dynamic queries and all, I have to use this stored procedure for sure)

So I am trying to execute the stored procedure as follows:

```
SqlParameter temp1 = new SqlParameter("@EffecitveDate", DateTime.Parse("01/01/2012"));
SqlParameter temp2 = new SqlParameter("@User_Key", id);

IEnumerable<UserEntity> usrEnt = context.Database.SqlQuery<UserEntity>("sp_Get_User @EffecitveDate, @User_Key", temp1, temp2);
```

But I am getting following error while executing the above line:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'UserEntity'. A member of the type, 'UserKey', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

I am really stuck on this please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all

Comment: Thanks! i will keep in mind about that.But do you have any idea how to fix that problem above?